# Is "but" an appropriate conjunction in the sentence "This can be graphed using anything, **but** I choose to graph it using Python"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

This [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-boxplots-5e2df7bcbd51) says

> This can be graphed using anything, **but** I choose to graph it using Python.

[OXFORD](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/but) gives this meaning

> Used to introduce a phrase or clause **contrasting** with what has already been mentioned.

and example sentence

> ‘he stumbled but didn't fall’

There is no contrasting in that post, is "but" an appropriate conjunction in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the word "but" is an appropriate conjunction in both sentences.

To my reading, both of the sentences involve a contrast of sorts.  In the second (easier) case it's a contrast between the stumbling and the not-falling.  In the first it's between "everything" and the specific tool used.

That said, there is a difference between the two.  A particular difference is that the first example would be equally correct without a conjunction at all.  Indeed, if I were writing it I would probably write:

"This can be graphed using anything; I choose to use Python."

Comment: You could also treat the stumble/fall example in the same way. Using 'and' in the first example sounds fine to me, but(!) it sounds a bit un-natural in the second.